# How do I perform an insecure URLSession query in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, https, urlsession

I'm trying to perform a query to a website that I run. However, currently, this website's certificate is invalid (for a valid reason for now).

I'm trying to query it with this code:

```
private static func performQuery(_ urlString: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return
    }
    print(url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }
        do {
            let productDetails = try JSONDecoder().decode([ProductDetails].self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(productDetails)
            }
        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

However, I get:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “mydomain.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

How can I make an insecure URLSession query (equivalent to -k in CURL)?

I've tried setting these:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mydomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

And yes I don't intend to release this to the App Store with insecure access, but I need to get the code tested and right now we can't get a valid certificate, so this is purely for development purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, set the delegate of the session to your class which conforms to `URLSessionDelegate` like :

```
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
```

Add the implementation of `didReceiveChallenge` method in your class which conforms to `URLSessionDelegate` protocol

```
public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}
```

This will allow insecure connection by trusting the server.

**WARNING** : DO NOT use this code in production apps, this is a potential security risk.

Comment: URLSession.shared.delegate = self doesn't work because delegate is get only

Comment: @Wayneio create a URLSession object with default session configuration and set it's delegate to your class. Use `init(configuration:delegate:delegateQueue:)`

Comment: Okay cool. So then to use it, I try let _ = session.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {... but it say session cannot be used on type 'Util' (Util is my class name)

Comment: Generally all your request code should be in a singleton class which has a session. For example, the class can be named as NetworkManager and it will have an instance of URLSession. You shouldn't perform requests from static methods of Utils.

Comment: Gotcha! This works! Somehow I'd removed the insecure loads bit from info.plist before, but with this too it's now returning data. Thanks.

Comment: @Wayneio glad it helped!

Comment: In iOS 12, Swift 4.2 in addition requires your class conforming to NSObject

Comment: It works, but in combination with NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = true setting

Answer (score 0):

Try these exceptions:

```
<key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
  <string>TLSv1.0</string>
  <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
  <false/>
  <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
<true/>
```